# Is there a way to calculate below chance performance on a multiple choice test

Tags: probability

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate below chance performance on a multiple choice test. The test has 25 questions with three response options. My respondent scored a 1.

I have mean scores and standard deviations for four different groups (I'm not sure if this information is needed) the mean score for one group ( the group with the lowest performance scores) was 13.3 (Sd 4.7)

Comment: Can you clarify qualitatively what you want to measure? By "chance performance" do you mean random guessing (e.g. $25\frac{1}{3}\approx 8.33$)? Or more relative to the other respondents (e.g. "off the curve", an outlier)?

Comment: please forgive my lack of knowledge here. I want to know if if my respondent's performance on the test was below change or by chance. I have used assessments ( typically true/false format) where I am able to obtain scores that correspond to "within chance performance" and "below change performance" and was wondering if i could calculate these same measures for the test i gave.

Comment: Do you mean guessing randomly on all questions? This is what I meant by my first option: 3 response options per question = a 1 in 3 chance to get it correct, so for 25 questions the expected score would be 25/3. So is this the sort of "chance" performance you had in mind?